# How to extract Bitmap data from TTF bitmap typeface for a POV display?

Tags: fonts, bitmap, processing, pixel, truetype

I have gathered together a number of 10 pixel-high bitmap typefaces from the dafont repository in TTF format. However, I'm having trouble extracting the actual bitmap data from them, as they seem to be in vector form and I cannot figure out the correspondence between point size and pixel size when rendering. I need suggestions for software tools, libraries or approaches to get the accurate per-pixel bitmap data corresponding with the letter forms.

An example font which makes sense of the problem is http://www.dafont.com/commodore-64-pixelized.font

My aim is to use one or more of these bitmap fonts to control an Arduino-based Persistence Of Vision (POV) display as part of the http://shrimping.it project.

POV devices use a line of LEDs to draw text in the air by flashing the LEDs on and off as the device is moved side-to-side. A well-known example is Adafruit's MiniPOV http://www.ladyada.net/make/minipov3/

To write the microcontroller code to flash the LEDs, I need to get the pixel-by-pixel information from the typeface, in other words I need a scheme to extract the data from the TTF format files I've been provided with to avoid having to do it manually for each character and each font.

So far I've been experimenting with Processing (http://processing.org), but I can't see how to select the point-size to render the TTF so that the font is drawn with an exact match to the underlying grid of pixels. Once I have this, I can derive the information, but I can't seem to get there. The textAscent and textDescent values reported by Processing seem to come out as junk, at least with the fonts I've tried.

The fonts I'm testing with are Advocut, Andina, Aux DotBitC, BM tube, Commodore 64 Pixelised, Homespun BRK, Nayupixel, SG05 and Visitor. You can retrieve any of these yourself by searching them at dafont.com if you need to see the original data to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix for this which is in three parts.

## Stage 1

First I used Python to output all the printable graphic ASCII characters, from the interactive python shell, by typing 'python' then ...

```
import string
print(''.join([chr(x) for x in range(33,127)]))
```

...which gives the following character sequence - omitting SPACE (32) and DEL (127)...

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

## Stage 2

Then I launched Inkscape, activated the visible pixel grid with View>Grid and created a text element containing all those characters in a line in the given font. I visually checked which characters had fallen back to a non-pixel glyph. (Where a character is not fully specified I think it inserts a regular vector font there which can be a non-integer number of pixels, which messes up the horizontal kerning and mis-positions the remaining characters so they must be substituted). I replaced any non-pixelated characters I saw with just a question mark, a character which seems to be reliably present and have an integer number of pixels in these typefaces.

Once all the characters are clean pixelated characters, With the text element selected, (making the coordinate bar appear at the top), and with the view zoomed in, I was then able to position the text at 0,0 and choose a pixel height manually which made the pixel elements line up with the backing grid (being sure that the lock symbol was activated to scale the horizontal and vertical dimensions together when I switched from 8,9,10,11 pixels high. In some cases these so-called 10 pixel fonts were actually 8 pixels or 11 pixels high when they lined up properly which explains some problems.

Sometimes the precise height mapping was a fraction off, so I tuned it by making sure the horizontal number of pixels was right (e.g. sometimes the actual height was fractional, like 618 pixels across but 7.005 high. By scanning along the characters you can see if pixels are slightly short or slightly long, and set the width to a whole number until the pixels fit the grid. The floating point difference in height is hardly visible in Inkscape and has no visible effect on export (where the fraction is rounded off) but if the horizontal count is wrong, the pixel mapping is shot and will produce horizontally blurred pixels because of the offset when you try to quantise.

Finally with the text element still selected, I chose File>Export Bitmap and chose the 'Selection' tab. Exporting a PNG with 8, 10, 11 or whatever number of pixels was discovered in the previous step, generates pixel graphics with a perfect pixel mapping - a file over which a simple routine can be written to extract the bitmap.

## Stage 3

Lastly a procedure must be written to import the PNG and extract the correct per-character information for the POV bitmap.

I came up with a routine which reliably detects the horizontal extent of characters, and can slice these into individual sequences for my POV. These are not monospaced typefaces, so the width of each character is unpredictable - e.g. the exclamation mark is often just two pixels wide. A special case needed to be coded in for the double-quote character which contains two gaps.

The source for my extraction routine is now at...

http://shrimping.it/shrimp/project/pov/font/extract_font.py

...and can be run over a set of png files in a directory by CDing to the directory and running

```
python extract_font.py
```

This then generates individual bitmaps for each character, extracted into a separate directory for each font.

Comment: Thanks to https://twitter.com/mgdm/status/259669824769245184 and https://twitter.com/gordonjcp/status/259664637342142464 for their suggestions via Twitter. Nothing yet via Stackoverflow :(

Comment: The Andina typeface seems to be unusable in its current form using this workaround as the spacing between letters varies and is often not an integer number of pixels (e.g. the ? and N character have partial pixel spacing).

Comment: The Nayupixel typeface has similar problems with spacing, but it's not quite so bad, and is recoverable simply by stretching the horizontal independently from the vertical, then flattening to a bitmap using Gimp's Image>Mode>Indexed>1bit color.

Comment: The resulting images for the fonts which were successfully mapped to bitmapped pngs can be downloaded at http://shrimping.it/shrimp/project/pov/font/png/

Answer (score 1):

## Python3

I've tried to be descriptive, but you can simplify to work how you need it to.

### Requirements: PIL (Pillow)

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)'s [ImageDraw](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagedraw.htm) and [ImageFont](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagefont.htm) module

```
# pip install Pillow
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

# use a truetype font (.ttf)
# font file from fonts.google.com (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Courier+Prime?query=courier)
font_path = "fonts/Courier Prime/"
font_name = "CourierPrime-Regular.ttf"
out_path = font_path

font_size = 16 # px
font_color = "#000000" # HEX Black

# Create Font using PIL
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path+font_name, font_size)

# Copy Desired Characters from Google Fonts Page and Paste into variable
desired_characters = "ABCČĆDĐEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSŠTUVWXYZŽabcčćdđefghijklmnopqrsštuvwxyzž1234567890‘?’“!”(%)[#]{@}/&\<-+÷×=>®©$€£¥¢:;,.*"

# Loop through the characters needed and save to desired location
for character in desired_characters:
    
    # Get text size of character
    width, height = font.getsize(character)
    
    # Create PNG Image with that size
    img = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    
    # Draw the character
    draw.text((-2, 0), str(character), font=font, fill=font_color)
    
    # Save the character as png
    try:
        img.save(out_path + str(ord(character)) + ".png")
    except:

        print(f"[-] Couldn't Save:\t{character}")
```